# How to query if object have nested array of object in mongodb using find or aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Below Object have key **dutys**. I want employee details from employee collection. So far I tried many combination of query with lookup with pipeline.
How to write query with find or aggregate

Collection have object data mention below

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("61332cbcf509434a28b1e42e"),
"name" : "Company 1",
"dutys" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("61332cbcf509434a28b1e437"),
        "duty_name" : "Front",
        "emp_ids" : [ 
            ObjectId("613329c9c2cd9949d3a7c630"), 
            ObjectId("613329c9c2cd9949d3a7c631"), 
            ObjectId("613329c9c2cd9949d3a7c632")
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("61332cbcf509434a28b1e438"),
        "duty_name" : "Cleaning",
        "emp_ids" : [ 
            ObjectId("613329c9c2cd9949d3a7c633"), 
            ObjectId("613329c9c2cd9949d3a7c634")
        ],
    }
  ]
}
```

I want expected output with employee details
For e.g. Expected output

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("61332cbcf509434a28b1e42e"),
"name" : "Company 1",
"dutys" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("61332cbcf509434a28b1e437"),
        "duty_name" : "Front",
        "emp_ids" : [ 
            {
               _id: ObjectId("613329c9c2cd9949d3a7c630"),
               name: "Emp 1",
            },
            {
               _id: ObjectId("613329c9c2cd9949d3a7c631"),
               name: "Emp 2",
            },
            {
               _id: ObjectId("613329c9c2cd9949d3a7c632"),
               name: "Emp 3",
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("61332cbcf509434a28b1e438"),
        "duty_name" : "Cleaning",
        "emp_ids" : [ 
            {
               _id: ObjectId("613329c9c2cd9949d3a7c633"),
               name: "Emp 4",
            },
            {
               _id: ObjectId("613329c9c2cd9949d3a7c634"),
               name: "Emp 5",
            }
        ],
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: could you provide sample data of emp ?

Comment: @mohammadNaimi Employee have only name, address like {
               _id: ObjectId("613329c9c2cd9949d3a7c634"),
               name: "Emp 5",
               address: "location 1",
            }

Answer (score 0):

`unwind` to destruct array

`lookup` to put orginal data instead of _id

`project` to add fields

`group` to create final data

```
db.collection('company').aggregate({
[
  {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$dutys'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'emp',  // emp collection name
      'localField': 'dutys.emp_ids', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'st'
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'name': 1, 
      'dutys.duty_name': 1, 
      'dutys._id': 1, 
      'dutys.emp_ids': {
        '$map': {
          'input': '$st', 
          'as': 'z', 
          'in': {
            '_id': '$$z._id', 
            'name': '$$z.name'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$name', 
      'dutys': {
        '$push': '$dutys'
      }
    }
  }
]})
```

Comment: I think u need to recheck your query

Comment: Can you please try to run below query. I dont know how to groupby and push empObjects in dutys: [{emp_ids: [empObjects1, empObjects2], _id: ObjectId("ss"), duty_name: "Front" }] . db.getCollection('vaccination_centers').aggregate([
{ 
    $unwind: {path: "$dutys", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } 
},
{
     $unwind: {path: "$dutys.emp_ids", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
},
{ 
    "$lookup": {
       "from": "emps",
       "localField": "dutys.emp_ids",
       "foreignField": "_id",
       "as": "empObjects"
    }
}

])

Comment: its different issue or related to my answer ?

Comment: with your query I am not getting expected result. so I write query u may help me to modify...may be our mongo version is different?

Comment: after updating my answer did you try it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236760/discussion-between-mohammad-naimi-and-naisarg-parmar).